# How to find maximum values from a list which contains objects in Python?

Tags: python

I have a class:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I create a list of objects of the above class Point which has field `x` and `y`.

I want to find maximum values of `x` or `y` of all objects from the list. For example from list `[Point(1,3), Point(5,2), Point(8,0)]` it would be 8.

I can do it as follows:

```
new_list = []
for point in points_list:
    new_list.append(point.x)
    new_list.append(point.y)

max(new_list)
```

What is the most elegant way to do it in Python?

Comment: Can you show what you have implemented already to see what your original approach is?

Comment: So you want to find the point object with the highest `x` or `y`.

Comment: @ChristianDean I want to find the max of y or x of all points. If I will find the object with highest x or y it will be OK.

Comment: What if the third item was `Point(0, 8)`? Would the answer still be 8, or would the answer be `3`?

Comment: @idjaw Currently I iterate through list and copy values of x and y to another list and then I use max build-in function on "another list".

Comment: @trojek Show your code. Also, please explain how exactly the max should be found. I asked a question based on a scenario in my comment. Please address.

Comment: #idjaw the answer will be still 8. I'm looking for the highest number of all numbers.

Comment: @trojek Update your question with that code. Don't put code in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vars` to return a dictionary of your instance's attributes then use the `.values` method to access the values.

```
>> class Point(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
... 
>>> points = [Point(1,3), Point(5,2), Point(8,0)]
>>> max_obj = max(points, key=lambda p: max(vars(p).values()))
>>> max_obj.x
8
```

If you are only interested in the maximum value, you can do something like this:

```
>>> max(map(lambda p: max(vars(p).values()), points))
8
```

If you find yourself frequently doing this, then you may want to implement the rich comparison ordering methods for your class and an instance method which returns the maximum value for the attribute.

```
In [7]: import functools

In [8]: @functools.total_ordering
   ...: class Point(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, x, y):
   ...:         self.x = x
   ...:         self.y = y
   ...:     def max_attr_value(self):
   ...:         return max(vars(self).values())
   ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
   ...:         return self.max_attr_value() == other.max_attr_value()
   ...:     def __lt__(self, other):
   ...:         return self.max_attr_value() < other.max_attr_value()
   ...:     

In [9]: points = [Point(1,3), Point(5,2), Point(8,0)]

In [10]: max(points).max_attr_value()
Out[10]: 8
```

Comment: This definitely cannot be the most elegant solution. That award should go to Christian Dean. As for performance, this isn't good either, because you keep querying a dict with the object's attributes. What if Point has other attributes? Such as distanceFromOrigin? Your approach won't work. @trojek, there were better approaches you could've used.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `max` function with a key:

```
max_obj = max(your_list, key=lambda p: p.x if p.x > p.y else p.y)
```

To get the maximum value, you can do

```
max_val = max_obj.x if max_obj.x > max_obj.y else max_obj.y
print(max_val)
```

Or (as OP suggests)...

```
max_val = max(max_obj.x, max_obj.y)
print(max_val)
```

Comment: It returns the object with max value, not max value.

Comment: Of course, it works but in my opinion, it is more elegant to use max_val = max(max_obj.x, max_obj.y).

Comment: @trojek Regardless of how you nitpick I still think this is an elegant solution. You yourself mentioned in the comments that getting an object was okay.

Comment: Yes getting an object is OK because it is quite easy to get the expected value. I vote up your answer and I think it is important but not the most elegant. It is, of course, subjective opinion.

Comment: You can use `max` inside `max`, and personally I find it easier to read: `max_obj = max(your_list, key=lambda p: max(p.x, p.y))`

Answer (score 3):

While you can use `max()` and `key` like @Coldspeed said, in the long term I believe a better solution would be to overload the less than and greater than operators for your `Point` class. That way you only have to implement the logic once. Also, if you decide to change the logic in the future, you'll only have to change it in one place:

```
>>> class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __gt__(self, point):
        return self.x > point.x or self.y > point.y
    def __lt__(self, point):
        return self.x < point.x or self.y < point.y


>>> points = [Point(1,3), Point(5,2), Point(8,0)]
>>> point = max(points)
>>> point.x
8
>>>
```

if you want to get the maximum value you can use a simple ternary condition:

```
max_val = point.x if point.x > point.y else point.y
```

Comment: Over engineered AF. But I had to upvote it. Good one. +1. In a larger application, I would go this route too. :)

Comment: @idjaw Really, you think so? This is default way I would do it. It makes for much cleaner code in my opinion. You define the logic once, and never have to worry about again :-)

Comment: I'm with you 100%. I would totally do this in my code. Personally, I absolutely love this! I think I'm just so used to SO answers always being one line *functional* answers, that when I see an elegant *readable*, *proper*, *testable* solution, it takes me by surprise. In short, good job. :)

Comment: But maybe this isn't how you *want* your `Point`s to be compared. Maybe you don't want points to be comparable, or maybe you'd rather use the euclidian distance or something like that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well in those cases, yes, my solution would suck :) But in all seriousness, if he needs different logic, all he has to do is change how the classes are overloaded. And if he doesn't want them to be comparable, just remove the methods. Simple.

Comment: But that's all speculation now. We have no idea what these calculations are for, or how they apply in context.

Comment: This code is clear. But it doesn't solve the problem in 100%. It returns an object, not the highest value. I need to use max(point.x, point.y).

Comment: @ChristianDean I'm not sure if I understand it (your last comment), but it will work only if x will be the max value. What in case if it would be y?

Comment: @ChristianDean Why don't you use build-in function max?

Comment: @trojek Using a built in function when it isn't needed is actually slower and has more of an overhead than using the construct of the language. Try a timeit and see.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward if you can choose the attributes you want to consider beforehand:

```
>>> points = [Point(1,3), Point(5,2), Point(8,0)]
>>> max(getattr(p, attr) for p in points for attr in ('x','y'))
8
>>>
```